# Como puedo conectar una vista y un controlador

Tags: php, symfony2, twig, mvc

**Contexto**

Estoy aprendiendo [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2) y estoy usando [twig](/questions/tagged/twig) para las vistas y quiero hacer una vista que se conecte con el controlador pero estuve leyendo y no entiendo muy bien cómo hacerlo.

**Pregunta**

¿Cómo aplicaría la arquitectura básica del [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc)? Y, a grandes rasgos, ¿cómo se podría implementar esta lógica en [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2)?

Comment: Qué versión de Symfony estás usando?

Comment: @rotvulpix la versión 2

Comment: @Sermanes Edité la pregunta para que sea más específica, orientándola específicamente a la muy buena respuesta que aceptaste. Sería recomendable que en futuras preguntas se busque orientar hacia una respuesta bien concreta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que entiendas la idea del MVC

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es la idea básica. Ahora del punto de vista de Symfony, funcionaría de la siguiente forma:

```
namespace Nombre\NamespaceBundleArtekBoard\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

//List es el nombre del controlador, acá uso una función userList (el Action es para identificar por symfony2 que usas una 'acción')
class ListController extends Controller
{
    public function userListAction()
    {
        return $this->render('NombreDelBundle:RutaDeLaCarpetaView:list.html.twig');
    }    
}
```

Y en la vista (list.html.twig, para este ejemplo)

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      Hola Mundo ^^
   </body>
</html>
```

Pero, cómo llego de la URL (por ejemplo www.dominio.cl/listarUsuario) al controlador y todo eso?, pues creo una ruta en el config/routing de mi Bundle

```
alias_de_yaml:
    path:     /user/
    defaults: { _controller: NombreDelBundle:List:userList }
```

(Nota que no se agrega el 'Controller' de UserController ni el Action de userListAction)

Ese sería un ejemplo muy básico de la idea que necesitas.

Un link interesante es este (está un poco viejo, ya que vamos en la versión 2.8.2 y 3.0.1) donde puedes aprender lo básico de Symfony2

http://librosweb.es/libro/symfony_2_4/

También si quieres puedes ver este 'proyecto' (que tengo tirado) usando Symfony 2.8 para que te hagas una referencia.

https://github.com/h40s4m4/ArtekBoard

saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias :)